# Сообщение JavaScript alert() на компонентах radio button

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Возник вопрос по поводу сообщения JavaScript alert() на компонентах radio button. А именно  на кнопку cancel. Как можно сделать, чтобы при выборе из группы компонентов radio button в выводимом окне alert при нажатии на кнопку cancel  возращало checked в исходное положение? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Эркин, не пойму, при чем тут alert(), но для сброса элементов формы к первоначальным значениям можно обойтись без JS, а использовать input с типом reset.

    <input type="reset">

Comment: Дело в том, что при выборе одного из компонентов radio button  у меня выводится сообщение alert с двумя кнопками OK и CANCEL, на OK  я решил проблему, а на CANCEL  у меня идет отмена, но не возвращается выбор на исходное место. Мне просто нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку CANCEl  чекед возвращался на свое место.

Comment: Окошко alert не может показывать больше одной кнопки.

Comment: @Эркин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В чем проблема? Используй

```
if(getElementById('Твой ид').confirm('Тра-ля-ля')) { Если выбрал ок } else { если нажал отмена }
```

alert показывает только ок, confirm ок или отмена.

Или ещё:

```
var tr = getElementById('Твой ид').confirm('Тра-ля-ля');
if(tr){ Если выбрал ок } else{ если нажал отмена }
```